# Get all Element Attributes from a Sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So i have a List of divs which are sortable using the Jquery UI option sortable.
Those divs contain some custom attributes using the setAttribute method like:
 `.setAttribute("Nr", "Nr_1")` and `.setAttribute("V", "V_1")`. I already can get an array of an singel Attribute using the `.toArray` method

`$("#NameContainer").sortable("toArray", { attribute: 'value'});` 

`$("#NameContainer").sortable("toArray", { attribute: 'Nr' });`

```
$("#NameContainer").sortable("toArray", { attribute: 'V' });
```

```
 <div id="NameContainer" class="ui-widget">
      <div value="Name_1" id="Name_1">John</div>
      <div value="Name_2" id="Name_2">Jack</div>
      <div value="Name_3" id="Name_3">Charlie</div>
      <div value="Name_4" id="Name_4">Sawyer</div>
      <div value="Name_5" id="Name_5">Yin</div>
      <div value="Name_6" id="Name_6">Ben</div>
    </div>
```

My Question now is how can i get all Attributes from every Elemente in the right order after they got sorted or course in a singel variable.
**UPDATE:**
So my first solution that is working as intented looks like that:

```
for(var i = 0; i<ArrayList.length; i++){
var attributeArray = [arrayValue[i], arrayNr[i], arrayV[i] ];
mainArray.push(attributeArray);
}
```

And then call the main: `mainArray[ ] [1]`

Comment: Are you saying you want to re-order them based on their attributes? Or that you want a string/array/some other data type containing the attributes in the order they are found?

Comment: I want a string/array/some other data type containing the attributes in the order they are found, sry for beeing unclear :(

Comment: All good, how are the attribute names all the same or are they all varying? Do you want the name of the attributes saved or the data those attributes contain saved?

Comment: they are all varying with an ongoing number like: Nr_2, V_2..

Comment: I just got an solution that is maybe not so nice but it works how intendend i update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Was only doing it for the main div container..fixed:

If you want to get the attributes in the order they are found then I think you can do something along the lines of:

```
var el = $('#NameContainer > div');

var nodes=[], values=[];
el.each(function() {
    for (var att, i = 0, atts = $(this).attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
        att = atts[i];
        nodes.push(att.nodeName);
        values.push(att.nodeValue);
    }
});
```

that will give you two arrays where the index i of nodes will give you the attribute name and the same index i of values will be the accompanying value of that attribute. this can be restructured in a number of different ways but this is a simple way to achieve your goal.